unexpected token ':', expected one of token or <phrase> sequence: ] <typ_args>? or <typ> . <id> -> <typ_nobin> and <typ>Motoko(M0001)
I'm new to Motoko and I tried this but the syntax seems to fail
With this line of Code
"    private var users : [Principal : Types.User] = [];
"
Here is where all the problem occurs, I can't deploy my canister without the right syntax of the codes
import Types "../types/Types";

module {
    private var users : [Principal : Types.User] = [];

    public func registerUser(user : Types.User) : async Result<Text, Text> {
        if (users.containsKey(user.id)) {
            return #err("User already exists");
        };
        users[user.id] := user;
        return #ok("User registered successfully");
    };

    public func loginUser(principal : Principal) : async Result<Types.User, Text> {
        switch (users.get(principal)) {
            case (?user) { return #ok(user) };
            case null { return #err("User not found") };
        };
    };

    public func getRole(principal : Principal) : async ?Types.Role {
        return switch (users.get(principal)) {
            case (?user) { ?user.role };
            case null { null };
        };
    };
};


import Principal "mo:base/Principal";

module {
    public type Role = { #Patient; #Doctor; #Researcher };

    public type User = {
        id : Principal;
        name : Text;
        role : Role;
    };

    public type HealthRecord = {
        patientId : Principal;
        doctorId : Principal;
        record : Text;
        timestamp : Int;
    };

};


